# how to create a console app in vs2017 with .net core 2.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just downloaded the latest Community Edition of Visual Studio 2017 and I want to create a console app. I have the following menu options:

- File > New > Project
- File > New > File

File > New > Project only has an option for "Blank Solution."  If I select the option to create a new solution then a new solution is created and displayed in Solution Explorer.

If I right-click the Solution in Solution Explorer and select Add > New Project then the "Add New Project" dialog is opened but no project types are available for selection. What do I need to do as next steps in order to create a new console app?

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio, what options did you install? Did you check the box for ".NET Core cross-platform development" workload?

Comment: I think I just did a basic standard install. I didn't make any special selections.  When I've installed Visual Studio in the past, I've just clicked install and accepted all of the defaults.  For this particular install, I think there was just a single "Install" button so I just clicked that button and let the install routine do its thing

Comment: Well learn to pay attention next time. Click Start, then search for Visual Studio Installer. Then find your instance and Modify it so that you choose all the options you will need to do your work.

Comment: @user8570495 " When I've installed Visual Studio in the past,", VS has an entirely new installation software, it's not even close to similar. You need to select the workloads you need.

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly select the needed frameworks when downloading Visual Studio.  Uninstall and Reinstall with the necessary options selected and your problems will be solved.